# fgets only read last line of file

Tags: c, parsing, fgets, scanf

Update:
As the comments below said, I checked the return value of sscanf, it quals to 2. I also checked the content stored in inClient[i].name and &inClient[i].waitTime. They are Ben and 4, respectively, which is the first line of input and no other values. I'm not sure where is the problem.

I have a trouble to parsing my input text file.
Here is a sample of my input file.

```
Ben     4
Mary    12
Anna    20
Gary    10
Jane    6
```

Here is my code.

```
int import_client(char* filename, Node* inClient)
{
    char inStr[100];
    //char* token;
    int i = 0;

    FILE* inFilePtr;
    if((inFilePtr = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL)
        printf("Error! Unable to open input file.\n");
    else
    {
        while(fgets(inStr, 100, inFilePtr) != NULL)
        {
            printf("%s\n", inStr);
            inClient[i].name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);
            sscanf(inStr, "%s %d", inClient[i].name, &inClient[i].waitTime);
            printf("%s\t", inClient[i].name);
            printf("%d\n", inClient[i].waitTime);
            i++;
            //printf("I'm here\n");
        }
    }

    fclose(inFilePtr);
    return(i);
}
```

Node is a structure with char* name and int waitTime in it. inClient is the Node* to the space I malloced space this function.

I have two problems.
1)The printf("%s\n", inStr); print and only print the last line of input file, i.e., Jane 60.
2)Even it prints the last line, but the number is wrong, which should be 6. I'm not sure why it adds a 0 at the end.

Comment: Check the return value from `sscanf()`.

Comment: 1) I guess like `while(fgets(inStr, 100, inFilePtr) != NULL);` 2) (1) print `Jane 60`. Check the contents of the file. Or `inClient` is not properly secured.

Comment: The code you've posted works as long as the file exists and has the text that you've shown. You should be checking the return value from `sscanf` as JohnZwinck said, and the `fclose` should be inside the `else` clause. Other than that, if you need help you'll need to post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can see what the real problem is.

Comment: You should show the definition of `Node`.

Comment: @user3386109 Thanks for your comments. I checked the return value of sscanf. It equals to 2. I also printed out the value stored inClient[i].name, and &inClient[i].waitTime. They are Ben and 4 respectively which is the first line of the input. I'm not sure what the problem is.